# Produce all possible combinations from GridView's selected cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am writing a web application in C#. I have a gridview in my page. It has 11 columns and 50 rows. There is a checkbox in each cell of the gridview. Users can select any number of checkboxes from any row. I need to produce all possible combinations of all selected checkboxes as for each combination at most there is one selected column per row. Row in which no columns are selected are ignored.

Let me explain via one example: consider below matrice is a short version of my gridview with 4 columns and 3 rows, row and column number are written. cells with "1" value show selected checkboxes.

```
   1 2 3 4
  ________
1| 0 1 0 1
2| 1 0 1 0
3| 0 0 1 0
```

As I said I want combinations in which in any row there is only one selected column. So there will be 4 different combinations:

```
(1,2), (2,1), (3,3)
(1,2), (2,3), (3,3)
(1,4), (2,1), (3,3)
(1,4), (2,3), (3,3)
```

How can i do it in C#? I already have arrays showing rows and columns of selected checkboxes, also I have an array which how many columns are selected in each row.

Thanks in advance for you helps and comments.

Comment: So the ASP.NET-GridView part is not relevant for the question, you know already how to get all selected cells? You want to know which are the possible combinations where only one column in a row is selected and if the user has selected one of those? Is that your requirement?

Comment: Yes maybe gridview is not relevant here, I just want to know how to produce all combinations

Comment: Guys really no one has any ideas, I am really Stuck in this problem